# How to fetch single row in one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate

```
public class ProfilePic  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private String picId;
 private String profilePicPath;
 private String smallPicPath;
 private String adddate;
 private Integer aid;
 //getter and setter
```

}

```
public class Atom implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String name;
//getter and setter
}
```

**Atom.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="test.Atom" table="atom" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="200" unique="true" />
        </property>
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ProfilePic.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="test.ProfilePic" table="profile_pic" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
        <id name="picId" type="string">
            <column name="pic_id" length="200" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="profilePicPath" type="string">
            <column name="profile_pic_path" length="1000" />
        </property>
        <property name="smallPicPath" type="string">
            <column name="small_pic_path" length="1000" />
        </property>
        <property name="adddate" type="string">
            <column name="adddate" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="aid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="aid" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to fetch only a single row from `ProfilePic`.
`Atom` and `ProfilePic` have one-to-many mapping(one atom can have multiple profilePic)

How to map for that.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to write a custom query (HQL/native SQL) behind a business method

Comment: I just started to learn this.

Comment: @bellabax please explain with its HQL query

Comment: Nope, too long. And not really related to your question. Are you learning HQL,right? Just study and try yourself and came back when you can be more precise than a "How to map it" and we will be happy to help you! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined relationship in `hbm.xml` files. Please make below changes

#### Atom.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="test.Atom" table="atom" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="200" unique="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="profilePics" table="profile_pic" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="aid" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="test.ProfilePic" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

#### ProfilePic.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="test.ProfilePic" table="profile_pic" catalog="xrcwrn_sms">
    <id name="picId" type="string">
        <column name="pic_id" length="200" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="atom" class="test.Atom" fetch="select">
       <column name="aid" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="profilePicPath" type="string">
        <column name="profile_pic_path" length="1000" />
    </property>
    <property name="smallPicPath" type="string">
        <column name="small_pic_path" length="1000" />
    </property>
    <property name="adddate" type="string">
        <column name="adddate" length="100" />
    </property>        
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Also need to change `.java` files

#### Atom.java

```
public class Atom implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Set profilePics = new HashSet(0);
 //constructor, getter and setter
}
```

#### ProfilePic.java

```
public class ProfilePic  implements java.io.Serializable {
  private String picId;
  private String profilePicPath;
  private String smallPicPath;
  private String adddate;
  private Atom atom;
 //constructor, getter and setter
}
```

### Related links

- [Hibernate docs many to one mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)
- [Hibernate one to many relationship example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/)

---

You need to share more about your question `fetch one row from ProfilePic`. Not very clear to me.

Comment: I want to fetch a single row from table, in one-to-many relationship